# Why post build changes in a file are not being reflected in the App Package?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2012, post-build-event, windows-store-apps

I'm modifying a file in a post build event, but the changes i make to the file don't reflect into the App package (Appx file), the file is included in the project as Content and the Copy to output directory property is set to Copy if newer, the changes are being reflected in the Debug build (bin\Debug) and the Deploy phase (bin\Debug\Appx).

I've tried, with Build Events and MSBuild Exec element and it doesn't work, do you have any ideas of what i may be missing? or a better way to achieve what i want to do?

Edit 1:

I took a look at the appxrecipe file (in the Debug folder), which i believe is being used to build the package, and found that the reference to the file points to the file in the Project directory, not the one in the Debug folder, so i made my post build tool to modify this file to point the reference to the modified file in the Debug folder, the change is made and it's reflected in the Deploy folder (vs.appxrecipe file) but the package still have the non modified file.

Comment: If you do a build with detailed or diagnostic logging verbosity, does your custom step run before or after the packaging step?

Comment: The custom step runs before the packaging step, i took a look at the appxrecipe file and found something interesting, i'll eidt my question to add it.